# to drive - who is the driver?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In a sentence:

**"I have to drive to the shop with my parents to buy a new phone"**

Does the writer imply that they are driving the car or a parent might be the driver too?

Comment: This a topic of some controversy, but generally if YOU have to DRIVE it implies that you are operating the car.

Comment: _Have to_ is the same as _must_ so it's the same question as _I must drive_; the subject is either driving or riding with parents. The construction is ambiguous. If you said _drive my parents to the shop_ then the parents would be riding, not driving. But it would still be unclear who's buying a phone.

Comment: @HotLicks, true, but people sometimes do say '**we**'ll drive to the store' (rather than take the bus), even though only one of them will actually operate the car; the OP might be extrapolating from such usage.

Comment: If I wasn't driving, I'd probably say "I have to go to the shop with my parents to buy a new phone" or maybe "My parents are driving me to the shop because I have to buy a new phone". It depends how important it is that you're going by car and who's driving, and what kind of coercion is involved (are your parents making you go, or do you need to go so your parents are taking you?)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the sentence is ambiguous. If the speaker is a minor this explains why their  parents are in the car, it would suggest the speaker is not driving. Or does the speaker already have a driver's license, and has no choice but to take heir parents to the shop so *they* can buy a new phone?  Who's buying and/or receiving a new phone, the speaker or the parents? Without context and details, there cannot be one single answer.

Answer (score 0):

The context I believe here is that you are a minor or at most a teenager and require an adult to be present or at least drive you to the store. I would be safe in thinking you're a passenger referring to a mode of private transport owned by a parent. If you were driving a parent to a store for new phone, a native English speaker would never have phrased it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the subject of "have to drive" is "I", so the speaker is driving.

However, sometimes one can "drive" in a non-literal sense. For example, one might say to another person "let's drive to the beach tomorrow" even if her or she expects the other person to drive. In that case, "drive" can be thought of as a group activity in which people travel together in a car.

I think that the second situation is rarer than the first, but it is possible if the speaker is speaking casually.